# The best way to deploy a demo version of a software product using SQL Server database

Tags: c#, .net, deployment, setup-deployment

We are trying to deploy a demo version of a program, which uses a relational database.

However, we have an issue:

If we use SQL Server Express as a backend database server, then clients have to download the SQL Server Express install file, which is huge and not desirable.

So my question is: Is there any alternative way of deploying the demo database, and then get the application running at the client's side without SQL Server?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: (1) the download is not ***huge*** by any means .... and (2) can't you just ship the SQL Server Express install package with your software, on disk?

Comment: Hi marc_s, let imagine that you have a slow connection 256 Kb/sec, and you have to download SQL Server Express Install( Around 700 Mb) and the program itself ( 200 Mb), it would take you about 2 hours just to have a quick look (for demonstration purposes). Probably, you wouldn't want to do that. Yes we ship the install file with the disk. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

Use SQL Server CE, it's only 1 dll (that you can distribute together with your application) and you can have your DB as a file.

Comment: Hi mate, I thought to use SQL CE as well. But don't know whether or not my scripts written in MS SQL server can be run on CE?

Answer (score 0):

Use Access.Access is a local light weight database.

Comment: Access requires office. Target computers might not have office installed.

Comment: Use XMl.Load XML to　DataTable and select by linq.

Comment: That's not Access. what are you talking about?

Comment: 1.Use Xml file store data.
2.Load xml file to DataTable when applicaiton launch.
3.Linq search.

Comment: No mate, I need a proper SQL database structure and don't want to re write my whole application.